# Oracle RTF template for etext - delete last row

Tags: bi-publisher

I have created a RTF template for generating a etext file in BI Publisher.  I have set NEW RECORD CHARACTER to Carriage return as I need each new record to start on new row. The problem is that after all XML data has been processed there is an empty row after the data. I need to remove that empty row but have had no success in doing so.

**Example:**

> firstname1;lastname1;
>
> firstname2;lastname2;<-file should end here, no enter after last
>   record

Any ideas please?

Template example:

```
<LEVEL> G_DATA
<MAXIMUM LENGTH>    <FORMAT>    <DATA>
<NEW RECORD>    ReportData
  50                Alpha     FIRST_NAME
                                ';'
  50                Alpha     LAST_NAME
                                ';'
< END LEVEL > G_DATA
```

Comment: There should be some other error in your template, is there a dangling "NEW RECORD" block which gets printed at the end ? The new line will be added only when it sees the "NEW RECORD" command.

Comment: Template is very simple and I don't get any errors with template viewer. Template looks like:                                                                     <LEVEL> G_DATA
<MAXIMUM LENGTH> <FORMAT> <DATA>
<NEW RECORD> ReportData
50   Alpha  FIRST_NAME
50   Alpha  LAST_NAME
<END LEVEL>G_DATA